# how the two event become workable simulatenously in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseover, jsni, mouseout

I am having a Label and the popup panel and when the mousemove over the label the popup will show and when the mousemove out of the label the popup will hide. I have completed till this but when the popup is showing and the cursor move inside it the popup will stay.I am facing the problem that the two events are not working simultaneously.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code? it will be more helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: label.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e)
{             body.appendChild(popup);                {             popup.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e)
{               body.removeChild(popup);            });} });}                       label.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e) {                body.removeChild(popup); });

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to write your code.

Comment: either the label is working together or if i remove the last listener than the popup listener will work i donot know what to do

Comment: Can you edit your question and add HTML and JavaScript code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/luckyyy/p3R8w/

Comment: Also add HTML to HTML block in fiddle.

Comment: actually i have written it in the jsni

Comment: please help if you have any idea...to how the event work correctly

Comment: Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/3xXM5/, it is working for me.

Comment: thanks you...but the popup is not staying when the mouse will move over it...I also want to have that ...

Comment: i would like to give the example as we are having the tags title and when the mouse is over that it will show and when the mouse is out it will become hidden and when the mouse is over the popup it will be staying..i want to have that functionality..

Comment: Can you use click event? It'll be much easier.

Comment: i have to work on mouse over and mouse out...means on mouse hovering

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/3xXM5/1/ , it works but you can make changes as you want.

Comment: thanks...but using this in my code the popup is not staying,please help if you have any other solution.

Comment: label.addEventListener("mouseover","mouseout",function(e {
                    alert(e.type);
                    if(e.type=="mouseover")
                    {
                     alert(hello);
                    }
               
           });

Comment: I have done the showing and hiding of popup in jqery,,,but still no benefit..http://jsfiddle.net/luckyyy/sXZFt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           var hideDelayTimer=null;
           var hideDelay=100;
           label.addEventListener("mouseover",function()
          {
            if(hideDelayTimer)clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

              alert('mouseover');
              label.appendChild(popup);     
          });

          label.addEventListener("mouseout",function()
            {   
            alert('mouseout');
            if(hideDelayTimer)clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
            hideDelayTimer=setTimeout(function()
            {
            hideDelayTimer=null;
            label.removeChild(popup);

           },hideDelay);
```